# Chamberlain belt appears too long

Tags: garage-door-opener

I bought a Chamberlain B750, but the belt appears to be several inches too long and will sag significantly when connected. 
Is this normal? Do I need to shorten the belt somehow?

[image: here is a picture how how much slack this will have]

Comment: Have you adjusted the spring trolley nut correctly?

Comment: You do not want to shorten the belt. If it's still too long after adjusting it, get with customer service to make sure you got the right belt for your unit.